# How to ensure every clients can execute Ajax with POST action?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am very new-hand with javascript.
I am writing a JS in our HTML page, which intend to logging some client-side information to our back-end side.

Here is my JS example in my page.

`where S is our JS framework , S.$ equivalent jQuery`

```js
<script>
    P.when("S").execute(function(S) {
        var $ = S.$;
        var sendInfo = {
          datas:[
            {
              data:{
                key1 : "v1",
                key2 : "v2",
                sTime: new Date().getTime() / 1000,
                eTime: new Date()
              }
            }
          ]
        };

        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "https://test.domain.com/post",
            data: JSON.stringify(sendInfo),
            dataType: "json",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8"
        });
    });
</script>
```

But after comparing with our other web server access log & data behind POST action, I found that there are some data lost with client-side Ajax posting.

So I am suspicious about my JS not so compatible with all client that causing some of client didn't execute this section

Could someone help me to review my JS code seeing that any improvement that can ensure all(or almost) clients can execute this section?
Many thanks.

Comment: jQuery can encode the data for you. Have you tried in the `ajax` argument putting `data: sendInfo`?

Comment: can you show the server code?

Comment: All clients can execute this code. Specify what data is "lost", exactly.